# What is the syntax meaning of RAISERROR()

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I just created a Instead After Trigger whose syntax is given below:

```
Create trigger tgrInsteadTrigger on copytableto
Instead of Insert as 
    Declare @store_name varchar(30);
    declare @sales int;
    declare @date datetime;

    select @store_name = i.store_name from inserted i
    select @sales = i.sales from inserted i
    select @date = i.Date from inserted i
begin
    if (@sales > 1000)
        begin
        RAISERROR('Cannot Insert where salary > 1000',16,1); ROLLBACK;
        end
    else
        begin
        insert into copytablefrom(store_name, sales, date) values (@store_name, @sales, @date);
        Print 'Instead After Trigger Executed';
        end
End
```

In the above syntax I have used `RAISERROR('Cannot Insert where salary > 1000',16,1)`

But when I write `RAISERROR('Cannot Insert where salary > 1000')` it gives the error "Incorrect syntax near ')'" on the same line.

Can anyone please explain the use of (16,1) here.

Comment: The syntax of `RaIsError` is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: This trigger is broken - it assumes that there's a *single* row in `inserted`, whereas in fact there can be 0, 1, or *many* rows in `inserted`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql

Comment: Related: For 2012+, the instructions say [not to use `RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and to [use `THROW` instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It is the severity level of the `error`.  The levels are from 11 - 20 which throw an error in `SQL`.  The higher the level, the more severe the level and the `transaction` should be aborted.

You will get the syntax error when you do:

```
RAISERROR('Cannot Insert where salary > 1000').
```

Because you have not specified the correct `parameters` (`severity level` or `state`).

If you wish to issue a warning and not an `exception`, use levels 0 - 10.

From MSDN:

> severity
>
> Is the user-defined severity level associated with this message. When
> using msg_id to raise a user-defined message created using
> sp_addmessage, the severity specified on RAISERROR overrides the
> severity specified in sp_addmessage. Severity levels from 0 through 18
> can be specified by any user. Severity levels from 19 through 25 can
> only be specified by members of the sysadmin fixed server role or
> users with ALTER TRACE permissions. For severity levels from 19
> through 25, the WITH LOG option is required.
>
> state
>
> Is an integer from 0 through 255. Negative values or values
> larger than 255 generate an error. If the same user-defined error is
> raised at multiple locations, using a unique state number for each
> location can help find which section of code is raising the errors.
> For detailed description [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321903)

Comment: Thanks, your answer clears my concept, but can you please explain the concept behind the state also, the third parameter of the RAISERROR().

Comment: @user2289490 - it can simply be used to determine where the error was thrown.  I.e. if you raise an error with state 1 and then another error (in a different part of your stored procedure) you can trace which part of your procedure threw the exception.

Answer (score 44):

16 is severity and 1 is state, more specifically following example might give you more detail on syntax and usage:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution to 
    -- jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
    -- information about the original error that caused
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
               @ErrorState -- State.
               );
END CATCH;
```

You can follow and try out more examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 13):

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
    { ,severity ,state }
    [ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
    [ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

`16` would be the severity.
`1` would be the state.

The error you get is because you have not properly supplied the required parameters for the `RAISEERROR` function.

Answer (score 8):

The severity level 16 in your example code is typically used for user-defined (user-detected) errors.  The SQL Server DBMS itself emits [severity levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) (and error messages) for problems it detects, both more severe (higher numbers) and less so (lower numbers).

The state should be an integer between 0 and 255 (negative values will give an error), but the choice is basically the programmer's.  It is useful to put different state values if the same error message for user-defined error will be raised in different locations, e.g. if the debugging/troubleshooting of problems will be assisted by having an extra indication of where the error occurred.

Answer (score 6):

The answer posted to this question as an example taken from [Microsoft's MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is nice however it doesn't directly demonstrate where the error comes from if it doesn't come from the TRY Block.  I prefer this example with a very minor update to the RAISERROR Message within the CATCH Block stating that the error is from the CATCH Block.  I demonstrate this in the gif as well.

```
BEGIN TRY
    /* RAISERROR with severity 11-19 will cause execution
     |  to jump to the CATCH block.
    */
    RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
               5, -- Severity. /* Severity Levels Less Than 11 do not jump to the CATCH block */
               1 -- State.
               );
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState    INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE();

    /* Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error
     | information about the original error that caused
     | execution to jump to the CATCH block
    */
    RAISERROR ('Caught Error in Catch', --@ErrorMessage, /* Message text */
               @ErrorSeverity,                           /* Severity     */
               @ErrorState                               /* State        */
               );
END CATCH;
```

[image: RAISERROR Demo Gif]